# Which annotation software can I use to annotate scope and focus?

Tags: semantics, software, annotation

I'm looking for an annotation software (no matter which OS), which lets me annotate focus and scope, as user-friendly as possible, e.g., via console input, or via a graphical editor (mouse-supported). Which tools fulfill these requirements?

Comment: Do you have your own notation codes for focus and scope, whatever you mean by them? Many tools allow for open-ended comments, where your codes could go.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Firstly, by focus I mean focus as explained [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28linguistics%29), and by scope I mean scope as in [this linguistic example sentence, also on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences#Scope_ambiguity_and_anaphora_resolution). The example sentence is linked to anaphora resolution, whereas I'm more interested in focus particles such as *only*, etc. I'm looking for a tool with which I can easily annotate a corpus of a some sentences with scope and focus annotations, preferably as a tree.

Comment: "Scope" in [anaphora resolution](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/PronounAntecedents.pdf), then. "Focus", on the other hand, is not really well defined by that page. There are a lot of ideas of what "focus" is, and every kind of theory has its own set of tests and definitions, so you'll have to pick your theory, and all its limitations, very carefully. And, once more, the system of annotation has to be consistent.